# How to make QTreeView display a subtree not on the first column

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a `QAbstractItemModel` with children on both the first and second column, like this:

```
item       item
├ item     subtree
|           ├ sub
|           ├ sub
|           | ├ subsub
|           | └ subsub
|           └ sub
├ item2    item
  ├ item
  └ item
├ item     item
|           ├ sub
|           └ sub
└ item     item
```

With `QTreeView`, I want to display `subtree`, eg. setting `subtree` as the `rootIndex`. When using `QTableView`, I have the subtree correctly displayed, however, only for the first level, as `QTableView` ignores nested indexes. With `QTreeView` no items are displayed.

I know that `QTreeView` expects the children to be on the first column, but I would assume this to be relative to the `rootIndex`. To add, setting the `rootIndex` to `item2`, I get the intended behavior, although for the wrong column / subtree.

One solution would be to separate the model into two smaller models, but I want to understand what the problem is.

I am thankful for any comments on how to display the `subtree` with a `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the unexpected behavior was due to some errors in the model implementation. `QTreeView` now sees the subtree correctly.